# WPF Splitter visibility

Tags: wpf, gridsplitter

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=CurrentNavigationView}" Visibility="{Binding NavigationPageVisibility}" Margin="2"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="3" Margin="1,6,1,6"  Visibility="{Binding NavigationPageVisibility}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{StaticResource NetApp_LightGray_Brush}" />
    <ContentControl    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2" Visibility="{Binding WelcomePageVisibility}" Content="{Binding Path=CurrentWelcomeView}" />
</Grid>
```

In the above xaml i am setting the visibility of the 1st content control and splitter based on some condition in my  ViewModel. But when in case i resize the splitter while running, then there is some empty space being shown before the last content control. I need the content control to occupy the complete real estate when i set the 1st content control and splitter  to collapsed?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `GridSplitter` messes with the `ColumnDefinitions`, once you grab it the first column will no longer be `Auto` but a concrete pixel value. Here is an example which shows this:

```
<Grid Height="100">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="c0" Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="c1" Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="c2" Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Width, ElementName=c0}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Width, ElementName=c2}"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
</Grid>
```

So if you want it to be collapsible again you need to return the `Width` to `Auto`.

Answer (score 1):

@Arihant,

1] Try `GridSplitter.HorizontalAlignment` as `Stretch`.

2] Is your `GridSplitter.Background` sensible enough to **display** the splitter?

3] Is `Visibility="{Binding NavigationPageVisibility}"` binding working? Do you see any binding errors on your `Output` window of your Visual Studio for this binding?

Is `NavigationPageVisibility` of type `Visibility` and of value `Visibility.Visible`?

Many developers declare such `NavigationPageVisibility` properties as boolean. That fails the binding.

4] Try to remove your `Margin="1,6,1,6"`. It can sometimes take the splitter off the visible area.

5] You **should not have `Grid.Row="1"`**. Splitter must always be at `Row="0"` and have a `Grid.RowSpan` maximum as possible. I set mine as 99.

Comment: NavigationPageVisibility sets Visibility correctly... Tried other steps mentioned here but no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: you set the visibility to `Visibility.Hidden`

This only hides the control, but they retain their space.

If you set the visibility to `Visibility.Collapsed` it should solve your problem.

Comment: No i have set the Visibility to Visibility.Collapsed. It works fine the first time, However, when i resize the columns using splitter, and then open the window again it shows some white space in the first column..